# Cannot install JavaFX Android app created by GluonHQ JavaFX - Why?

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon-mobile

I have just made a booking system, very simple for basic use. I got 2 issues with the application on mobile side. On Desktop side - No problem.

**Issue 1:**
When I try to install the application on my Android phone (6.0.1), then it won't install. I tried to a new phone and the application could be installed on the new android phone. My old phone says "The application will not be installed". No more futher information. No error logs etc.

**Iusse 2:**
When I try to shift page in the application from the new Android phone, then the application shuts down.
When I press "Skapa ny användare" (Create new user), then it supposed to shift the page to another page. But the application shuts down on Android phone.

[image]

Code :

```
   /**
     * When we press the URL link "New user"
     * @param event
     */
    @FXML
    void newUser(ActionEvent event) {
        MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(Main.NEWUSER_VIEW); // Here the application shuts down - Why?
    }
```

Source: [LoginPresenter.java](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/BooK/blob/master/BooK/BooKApp/src/main/java/se/danielmartensson/views/LoginPresenter.java)

My project is located here:
https://github.com/DanielMartensson/BooK

Do you know how I can solve thise two issues?

**Edit2:**

After running `adb logcat` and run the application, I could see this.

[image]

Comment: Are you using `adb logcat` to see the output during the process? About the first case, where do you see the message `"The application will not be installed"`, running `./gradlew androidInstall`? In that case run `./gradlew --info androidInstall`, and see if you get a more detailed output.

Comment: @josépreda Thank you for your reply. Do I need to have the phone connected via USB? Imorgon just run /gradlew android

Comment: To create and install the apk you have to run `./gradlew androidInstall`, the `android` task only produces the apk file (this can also be installed with `adb`). To run `adb logcat` you need to plug your phone, indeed.

Comment: Just a guess. Set the minSDK in the android manifest file to the version of the old phone

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried to install on KitKat 4.4.4 and it worked. sdkTarget 19. But when I try to switch page, then the application stops. Yes. I installed with androidInstall and plugged in the phone into the USB.

Comment: @JoséPereda Can it be that I'm using Httpd as dependency?

Comment: Whenever you have an error, `adb logical` will tell you what went wrong, you will see an exception and its full stack trace, so you can fine what is causing it. `adb` can be found in the `platform-tools` folder under Android SDK path.

Comment: @JoséPereda I started `adb logcat`, then I run `gradlew androidInstall`, then I start my application and it shut down after I switch page. Then I run `adb logical` and here is the output. "adb.exe logical unknown command"

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb. You have to run `adb logcat` from a terminal, with your phone plugged, you should see a lot of messages coming out from it. Then launch your app, make sure you see in the terminal the messages related to the app process, and then make it crash. You should see the exception in the terminal. Then stop logcat (Ctrl+C) and analyze the exception.

Comment: @JoséPereda Now I have get an error and I have posted a picture in my question.

Comment: Try converting the name of your fxml files to all lowercase. I recall some issues with Afterburner on Android.

Comment: @JoséPereda Now I can switch page! :) Thank you. Now I realize that HttpClient won't work for Android. Guess I have to use standard Http Client from Java 8.